# How to Fix CSS delivered wrongly as "Text/Html"?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, encoding, mime-types

I have an `.htaccess` that redirects all requests to a script file (`redirect.php`).

The script file makes an include of the page called, lets say `index.html`. Same goes for all sources in the page (`.jpg`, `.css`, etc).

Problem is that `CSS` files are served as `HTML`.

When I check the response headers, it says `Content Type : text/html` instead of `text/css`.

I have tried :

- [This solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/348439/how-to-fix-apache-content-type-for-php-parsed-css) : still doesn't work.
- Putting `AddType text/css .css` in the `.htaccess` before or after the `RewriteRule` it already contains : still doesn't work.
- Putting `type="text/css"` in the HTML `<link>` tag : still doesn't work

How could I fix it so CSS is served as `CSS` rather than `HTML`?

**EDIT**

The basic `.htaccess` I use is :

```
AddType text/css .css
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .css
<Files *.css>
  Header set Content-type "text/css"
</Files>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/redirect.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) redirect.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can we see your .htaccess?

Comment: One more -- sorry, just checking -- if you visit your CSS file's URI in the browser, is it definitely correct? Or is it showing a 404?

Comment: Yes as I said it shows up as text/html (I checked the response headers).

Comment: Just checking - I've previously had the same problem, only to discover that the header was `text/html` because the CSS file wasn't there and Apache was just giving me its 404. Next question: if everything is going through redirect.php, why the `${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`?

Comment: That's true, maybe useless, but still doesn't work without !

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is obviously wrong with your .htaccess. I used [this site](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) to test `http://hostname/style.css` with this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ redirect.php?q=$1 [NC,L]
```

The resulting URL was `redirect.php?q=style.css`. This *should* work, assuming that your PHP file sets the appropriate headers using `<?php header('Content-Type: text/css');`

If the problem persists, the only other idea that comes to mind is that your CSS file really isn't there. If you're trying to include `http://mywebsite/style.css`, go to a terminal and `curl http://mywebsite/style.css`, just to check that it definitely isn't Apache's 404 page. If that does turn out to be the problem, then it's simply that you're using the wrong CSS file path.

Comment: I would like to use `header('Content-Type: text/css');` as you suggested, but how could I do this on every css ? (without renaming css files to php files)

Comment: If they're all going through `redirect.php`, check the extension in that file. `if (substr($_GET['q'], -4) === '.css') header('Content-Type: text/css');` - obviously, you're going to need to add a few checks (`isset ($_GET['q'])`, is it the right length, is it a valid path, etc...)